# Ruby regular expression for version numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write a program which takes build number in the format of `23.0.23.345` (first two-digits then dot, then zero, then dot, then two-digits, dot, three-digits):

```
number=23.0.23.345
pattern = /(^[0-9]+\.{0}\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]$)/

numbers.each do |number| 
    if number.match pattern
        puts "#{number} matches"
    else
        puts "#{number} does not match"
    end
end
```

Output:
I am getting error:
floating literal anymore put zero before dot

Comment: `number=23.0.23.345` should be `number = '23.0.23.345'`

Comment: What do you want to do: find and split it or validate it?

Comment: try this pattern `/\d{2}\.0\.\d{2}\.\d{3}/` right now your pattern is one or more numbers, zero periods,period, one or more numbers, period, one number. [Example of my regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/nX4wR7/1). [Example of your regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/pL9pM2/1). Regex101 has a nice description on the right hand side to tell you what your regex is doing.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use something like this to find patterns that match:

```
number = 'foo 1.2.3.4 23.0.23.345 bar'
build_number = number[/
  \d{2} # two digits
  \. 
  0 
  \. 
  \d{2} # two more digits
  \.
  \d{3}
/x]
build_number # => "23.0.23.345"
```

This example is using String's [`[/regex/]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method, which is a nice shorthand way to apply and return the result of a regex. It returns the first match only in the form I'm using. Read the documentation for more information and examples.

Your pattern won't work because it doesn't do what you think it does. Here's how I'd read it:

```
/(       # group
  ^      # start of line
  [0-9]+ # one or more digits
  \.{0}  # *NO* dots
  \.     # one dot
  [0-9]+ # one or more digits
  \.     # one dot
  [0-9]  # one digit
  $      # end of line
)/x
```

The problem is `\.{0}` which means you don't want any dots.

The `x` flag tells Ruby to use multiline, which ignores blanks/whitespace and comments, making it easy to build a pattern that is documented.

Comment: didn't know you can use newlines so freely in ruby regexes, looks great.

Comment: There's a time and a place for them. The `x` flag can be great when dealing with really weird patterns, and it can then turn right around and bite us because we'll forget to add a `\s` to explicitly mark where a whitespace should be.

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use a gem like [versionomy](http://dazuma.github.io/versionomy/). You can parse the versions, compare them, check for equality, increment a particular part, etc. It even handles alpha, beta, patchlevels, etc.

```
require 'versionomy'

number='23.0.23.345'

v = Versionomy.parse number
v.major #=> 23
v.minor #=> 0
v.tiny  #=> 23
v.tiny2 #=> 345
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = "23.0.23.345", "23.0.33.173", "0.0.0.0"
pattern = /\d{2}\.0\.\d{2}\.\d{3}/x

numbers.each do |number| 
   if number.match pattern
    puts "#{number} matches"
   else
    puts "#{number} does not match"
   end
end
```

The "number" array in line one needs to have values of strings and not integers, I also changed the array "number" to "numbers", you will also need multiple items in the numbers array to call the ".each" method in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be agreement on what regular expression you should use. If your ultimate goal is to extract the elements of the strings as integers, you could do this:

```
str = "I'm looking for 23.0.345.26, or was that 23.0.26.345?"
str.scan(/(\d{2})\.(0)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{3})/).flatten.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [23, 0, 26, 345]
```